# Form dynamic added element, and send like array, but the index's are not maintained

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form and the elements are added dynamically

```
<form action="somepage.php">
  <table id="content">
  </table>
</form>
```

Via two inputs I accept two values

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
<input type="text" name="content" id="content">
```

When I add a element via javascript then the form is like this

```
<form action="somepage.php">
    <table id="content-main">
       <tr>
         <td>This is a title
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a title" name="titles[0]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
         <td>This is a content
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a content" name="content[0]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Then the elements are saved in "titles" array and "content" array, see there is a button with the class "remove", this is an option that remove the elements if the user have a mistake and need to delete the element

The point, is when there are element added and elements deletes, the content of the form, as an example:

```
<form action="somepage.php">
    <table id="content">
       <tr>
         <td>This is a title
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a title" name="titles[0]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
         <td>This is a content
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a content" name="content[0]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>This is a title
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a title" name="titles[3]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
         <td>This is a content
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a content" name="content[3]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>This is a title
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a title" name="titles[6]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
         <td>This is a content
            <input type="hidden" value="This is a content" name="content[6]">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The user has remove the element 2,4,5

Like see, the index are different, the way that I imagine, is when delete a element, via Javascript re-index all element, but I don't known if this is the right way.

For add the elements via Javascript I use jQuery and Underscore templates:

```
<script>
var title = $("#title").val();
var content = $("#content").val();
var index = 0;
var tmpl = _.template($("#template").html());
$("#content-main").append(tmpl({ title: title, content: content, index: index++});
</script>
```

Comment: how you are assigning indexes to elements title[x] or content[x]..? and whats you end goal to reassign indexes or get values?

Comment: Via javascript, jquery and underscore templates, I edit, the post and put an example

Comment: end goal?? get values or only keep indexes??

Comment: post the form, with the elements with the right index, for iterate via php

Comment: If you’re hoping to post this form to php I would suggest you use empty array brackets for the fieldnames, eg `name=‘titles[]’`.  If you need to pass the index through then add a hidden form element to the template which contains the index.

Comment: seems like you only want to get values also from your code it looks like indexes are only for differentiating purpose so simply keep the "name" property for all titles same and for content elements same and post the form php will do the magic for you and collect them in single array title[] for title and content[] for content something like `<input type='text' name='title[]'>`